What is the name of this American movie where the employee can go underground by an elevator?
So, I watched this movie on Cinemax about 5 years ago but I don't remember its name.
The movie is about a man who just got a new job and moved into this building. The building had two parts and he worked underground. he and other employees went down there by elevator. The underground part had 2 groups which all want to have a thing (I don't remember what it is). The man met his ex there and they started a new relationship. After all, the employees of 2 sides killed each other to take the thing. The man and his ex protected themselves during the fight. In the fight, they killed the other in a thrilling way. After all, they survived and got the thing. When they open the elevator, he killed her. He took the thing back home for him mom.
So I hope this information is enough. Will definitely keep on updating if anything comes into mind.

Operation: Endgame maybe with Odette Annable, Rob Corddry, Maggie Q, Zach Galifianakis, etc. ?

I really wanted this movie to be called "Get the Thing!"

You're looking for "Operation: Endgame".  This movie came out in 2010, which matches up to your suggestion of "5 years ago".  The movie stars Joe Anderson and features an ensemble cast, including Zach Galifianakis, Maggie Q, Rob Corddry, Adam Scott and Bob Odenkirk (Better Call Saul).  Here is the plot summary on Wikipedia.  As you read through, I'm sure it will be evident that this is the movie you described.  
One interesting note is how you said "he took the thing back home for him mom".  It is noted that he says "ma'am" in an English accent, so it sounds like mom.

Please add a synopsis or explain why you think the movie you listed is the correct one. Use imdb.com if you need help.

This is the right movie because it matches the movie plot perfectly.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operation:_Endgame#Plot

Instead of commenting, you might consider editing your answer to provide more detail. You might get some upvotes as a result.
